# How to call different queries in a nested loop with pyodbc

Tags: python, ssms, pyodbc

I have something like

```
cursor.execute("select * from table1") # table1 has 10 rows
for k,row in enumerate(cursor,1):
    if row[3] != None:
        cursor.execute("select * from table2") # table2 has 10 rows
        for row2 in cursor():
            print(row2)
    print(row)
```

SQL doesn't allow multiple cursor within same come connection. Then how can i fetch data from table2

Comment: What is the logic behind these queries and can you share some sample data which might explain your question?

Comment: table1 :student (rollno,name,adderess,ZIPCode ) ; table2 : area (zip, city); If I want to fetch city by ZIP for student whose ZIPCode is stamped in student table.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like perhaps you should be doing a join between the two tables:

```
sql = """SELECT s.rollno, s.name, s.adderess, s.ZIPCode, a.city
         FROM student s
         INNER JOIN area a
             ON s.ZIPCode = a.zip"""
cursor.execute(sql)
for row in cursor():
    print(row)
```

The reason you were finding Python's syntax to be insufficient for your requirements is that the relation of one table to the other is something which is intended to be handled from the database, not within Python.